# Multiply row values by a dynamic value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm relatively new to Excel, and I'm working on a spreadsheet that assigns a person a completion percentage based on the number of missions he has completed throughout a given week.
Each mission has a different weight. So for example, for week `x` for person `y`:

```
Mission 1 (weight1 - 0.2) - V
Mission 2 (weight2 - 0.5) - V
Mission 3 (weight3 - 0.3) - X
Completion percentage: 70%
```

The problem I'm facing is with calculating the `Completion percentage`.
I could use `COUNTIF((mission1cell), V) * weight1 + COUNTIF((mission2cell), V) * weight2` and so on, but this solution looks terrible and time consuming to me.
I tried using arrays but it didn't quite work for me.

How else can I calculate `Completion percentage` for this case?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a new column with the following formulae

```
= IF(missioncell == "V", weightcell, 0)
```

and then just do a sum on that column. upside is that,

1. you can insert a new row if there's a new mission you can just drag
2. the formulae down instead of having to type it in.